# Adding non adjacent elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

I've been stuck on a simple problem for a while. Let's say you have a list of any length:
`{a,b,c}`
How do you recursively add the first and last element of the list until you get to the middle.
For example:
`{a+c,b}`

Thanks

Comment: `(Assuming the list will always have an even number of elements` but your example you gave `{a,b,c}` has odd number of elements? and to be more clear, if the input is say  `lst = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` what should the output be? And why does it have to be recursive?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, the final list then should have only 3 elements in it?

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on the length of the original list which will have odd number of elements

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[f0]
f0 = Total @ PadRight @ {#, Reverse@#2} & @@ TakeDrop[#, Floor[Length[#]/2]] &;

f0[{a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {a + c, b}
> ```

```
f0[{a, b, c, d}]
```

> ```
> {a + d, b + c}
> ```

```
f0[{a, b, c, d, e}]
```

> ```
> {a + e, b + d, c}
> ```

```
f0 @ Array[x, 7]
```

> ```
> {x[1] + x[7], x[2] + x[6], x[3] + x[5], x[4]}
> ```

```
f0 @ Array[x, 8]
```

> ```
> {x[1] + x[8], x[2] + x[7], x[3] + x[6], x[4] + x[5]}
> ```

Also (for lists of odd length):

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3, f4, f5]
f1 = Module[{l = (Length[#] - 1)/2}, 
    Join[#[[;; l]] + #[[-1 ;; -l ;; -1]], {#[[l + 1]]}]] &;

f2 = Module[{l = (Length[#] - 1)/2}, 
    Append[Total[{#, Reverse@#2} & @@ Partition[#, l, l + 1]], #[[l + 1]]]] &;


f3 = Module[{l = (Length[#] - 1)/2}, 
    Join[Table[#[[i]] + #[[- i]], {i, 1, l}], {#[[l + 1]]}]] &;

f4 = Module[{l = (Length[#] - 1)/2}, 
    Join[Total[{#, Reverse @ Rest @ #2}], {First @ #2}] & @@ TakeDrop[#, l]] &;

f5 = Module[{l = (Length[#] - 1)/2}, 
    Join[Total[{#, Reverse @ #3}], #2] & @@ TakeList[#, {l, 1, l}]] &;
```

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to recognize that adding the first and last elements repeatedly is the same as adding the list to a reversed version of the list. Hence:

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e};
(list + Reverse[list])[[1 ;; Ceiling[Length[list]/2]]]

{a + e, b + d, 2 c}
```

If you really don't want the final term doubled (for odd-length lists) then divide the final element by 2.

Answer (score 3):

Exploiting the fact that `Flatten` can transpose a ragged array:

```
{a,b,c} // Flatten[{Take[#,Floor[Length@#/2]], Reverse@Take[#,-Ceiling[Length@#/2]]},{{2}}]& 
        // Plus@@@#&
```

> {a + c, b}

```
{a,b,c,d,e} // Flatten[{Take[#,Floor[Length@#/2]],  Reverse@Take[#,-Ceiling[Length@#/2]]},{{2}}]& 
            // Plus@@@#&
```

> {a + e, b + d, c}

```
 Array[x, 7] // Flatten[{Take[#,Floor[Length@#/2]],  Reverse@Take[#,-Ceiling[Length@#/2]]},{{2}}]& 
             // Plus@@@#&
```

> {x[1] + x[7], x[2] + x[6], x[3] + x[5], x[4]}

```
 {a,b,c,d} // Flatten[{Take[#,Floor[Length@#/2]],  Reverse@Take[#,-Ceiling[Length@#/2]]},{{2}}]& 
           // Plus@@@#&
```

> {a + d, b + c}

Answer (score 3):

you can use recursion to solve it.

```
Which[
Length@# == 1,   #,
True,            {First@# + Last@#, #0[# // Rest // Most]} // Flatten
] &@{a, b, c, e, f, g, h, i, j}
```

or

```
Which[
Length@# == 1,   #,
True,            Join[{First@# + Last@#}, #0[# // Rest // Most]]
] &@{a, b, c, e, f, g, h, i, j}
```

It's easy to find that each operation make the first and last element to the head of list, and the operation will be on the `[[2;;-2]]` part.

Comment: there is another way, which maybe more intuitive?  `Prepend[#0[# // Rest // Most], First@# + Last@#]`

Answer (score 2):

**Using `FoldPairList`:**

Define a function to insert a `0`, if the list has odd length.

```
f[k_List] := 
 If[OddQ[Length@k], Insert[k, 0, 1 + Ceiling@(Length@list/2)], k] &@
  list

f /@ {{a, b, c, d, e}, {a, b, c, d, e, f}}
```

{{a, b, c, 0, d, e}, {a, b, c, d, e, f}}

---

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e};
FoldPairList[{First@# + Last@#, Most@Rest@#} &, f[list], 
 ConstantArray[1, Length@f[list]/2]]
```

> {a + e, b + d, c}

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
FoldPairList[{#[[1]] + #[[-1]], #[[2 ;; -2]]} &, f[list], 
 ConstantArray[1, Length@f[list]/2]]
```

> {a + f, b + e, c + d}

For learners that are new to `First`, `Last`, `Most`, `Rest` usage, an alternate syntax using `Part` is provided in the second example above that will help with learning.

Comment: (+1) I won't forget this use of `FoldPairList`.